# Why am i receiving a blank PDF when attempting to GET from an HTTPS url, but not from an HTTP url?

Tags: typescript, https, axios

I am using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to perform http/https GET functions to retrieve a PDF document and save it in a database. It functions perfectly when accessing an HTTP url, however when trying to pull a PDF from an HTTPS url, it returns a blank PDF with the same page count. What am I missing here?

```
const data = await axios({
  url: url,
  method: 'get',
  responseType: 'blob',
}).then((response) => {
  return response.data;
});

return Buffer.from(data);
```

Comment: what do you get in the error logs? can you also tell what's the response's status code? also, if you are using `await` why do you have `.then`?

Comment: there are no errors thrown, it is technically returning an object as expected, it just has no actual content and each page is completely blank. This is just the way that I got it working, if you can provide a better layout/format then I would be grateful :)

Comment: can you try the same thing in postman? and see if you get the same blank results?

Comment: I've never used Postman, I wouldn't even know where to begin

Comment: postman is a very simple tool for trying out rest APIs, it's just a developer tool ( has nothing to do with your code ), doing all kind of request will be like using a browser in that.... so, once it works there, you can make it generate the code  & just slap it on your code 

Comment: its just a get request for a URL so the code isn't any different, simply pasting the link into postman works but it still doesnt work in my application